# ssh multiplexing via port forwarding

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, multiplexing

I'm trying to create a setup where one could "ssh" to a specific port on localhost and then get *forwarded* to a remote server and into a shell, without the need to enter credentials (nope, secret key is not an option, unfortunately).

So far I have set up ssh multiplexing, with `ControlMaster`, so I can start a remote ssh shell without any prompts, from the local shell.

Is there a way to use that socket when new client connects to a specific port on localhost?

I've tried various combinations with `-D`, `-R` and `-S`, with no luck. Is such a setup possible, on either Linux or Mac?

**edit:**

I don't mind entering localhost credentials at any point, but I'm trying to avoid entering remote credentials for all connections following the initial control connection.

---

```
localhost        ---->    localhost:2222             ---->   remote:22
  $ ssh -p 2222             forward to remote                  $ _ :)
                            using an existing 
                            control socket
```

Comment: Well that sounds incredibly insecure.

Comment: If you want ssh without security it's called rsh.

Comment: It shouldn't be insecure, because a) there needs to be an open control connection, and that requires credentials, and b) closing port 2222 for everything but local traffic should protect it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a basic shell, you could use `netcat` to create a shell listening on a certain port on remote server, and use Port Forwarding on local ssh to create the tunnels:

On remote:

```
while true ; do netcat -l -p 15000 -e /bin/bash ; done
```

On local:

```
ssh -L 5000:remoteip:15000 user@server
netcat localhost 5000
```

You will not be able to use some commands (vim behaviour is *funny*), but it works for most commands. Every time the connection is closed, the loop will spawn a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You could always reroute (forward) `localhost:2222` `localhost:22` using iptables, eg.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2222 -j REDIRECT --to-port 22`

See [alias port / port forwarding to another local port](https://serverfault.com/questions/251225/alias-port-port-forwarding-to-another-local-port) or this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+port+forwarding&oq=linux+port+forw&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l2j69i64l2j69i60l2.2248j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). This, in addition to [`ControlMaster auto`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing#Setting_Up_Multiplexing), should not require any additional passwords (either local or remote).

However to me this seems unnecessary and makes me wonder if you don't have a case of the XY problem.